# Parse some tricky HTML with nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse this html with Nokogiri, but I'm stuck.

```
<b>Dudule Francis</b>
<br>
<b>Tél. : </b>
01 02 03 04 05
<br>
<b>Fax : </b>
10 90 80 70 60
```

I would like to extract the first phone number `01 02 03 04 05`. It's between `</b>` and `<br>` and only when `<b>Tél. : </b>` is spotted. If someone got a clue, I'm open.

Comment: Thank you @sawa for the clean, sorry ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
noko = Nokogiri::HTML(html_text)
noko.xpath("//b[text() = 'Tél. : ']").each do |b|
  puts b.next_sibling.content.strip
end
# 01 02 03 04 05
```

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thank you. 
But i want to understand this syntax : //b[text() = 'Tél. : ']
did not get the [text() = 'Tel. : ']

Comment: `[text() = 'something']` means "with a text content equal to 'something'"

Comment: Simple ... Going to reread all the Noko documentation. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
doc.at('b[text()="Tél. : "]').next.text
```

If for some reason you want to make sure it's between the b and the next br:

```
doc.at('b[text()="Tél. : "] + br').previous.text
```

Answer (score 1):

I find CSS easier to understand a lot of the time, and, though CSS by itself can't usually look inside the text of a node, forcing us to use XPath, Nokogiri gives us some added help using jQuery's extensions:

```
doc.at('b:contains("Tél.")').next_sibling.text.strip
"01 02 03 04 05"
```